# How to remove file while installation/uninstallation?

Tags: installshield, installshield-2013

I have created a MSI installer using InstallShield. I want to remove some files while upgrade/installation/uninstallation. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one in-built CustomAction in InstallShield, RemoveFiles. This CA removes all files while uninstallation. But if we want to remove some files while fresh installation or while upgrade installation then we can use FileRemove table. [RemoveFile table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371201(v=vs.85).aspx) can explain all the fields of it.

In InstallShield, you can access this table from Additional Tools->Direct Editor->RemoveFile. In this table you need to add entry of a file that we want to be remove.